# How to deserialize real world JSON in Symfony2

Tags: php, json, symfony, serialization

I have a directory into which some json files are regularly updated. What I want to do is deserialize them in my Symfony2 application to get at their juicy data.

The examples on the symfony site include extremely simple flat JSON examples, that do not reflect the nested reality of real world nested JSON data. For example, the following is a simplified version of the files I want to deserialize.

```
{
    "uid" : "some unique identifier"
    "title" : "this is a tile",
    "description" : "some description",
    "paragraphs" : [
        {
            "position" : "left",
            "body" : "a lot of text here",
            "video":{
                "ogg" : "path1",
                "webm" : "path2",
                "mp4" : "path3"
            }
        },
        {
            "position" : "right",
            "body" : "a lot of text here",
            "video":{
                "ogg" : "path1",
                "webm" : "path2",
                "mp4" : "path3"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Of course, I want to deserialize this nested JSON into a simple, easy to access, model.

What I want to know is how to write the `Content` class for the above JSON so that when I call `$filecontent = $serializer->deserialize($data, 'Acme\Content', 'json');` it deserializes successfully.

Comment: In PHP, you can do it with one function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php. Have you tried this? If so, why is it not viable? Let us know your desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should deserialize your JSON with ease:

```
$fileContent = json_decode($jsonData);
```

[Documentation for json_decode can be found here](http://php.net/json_decode)

Comment: Simplest approach, so I used it. 
Hoped that there was a way to do it in the framework without having to write a ton of scaffolding, but not so.

Comment: Well, you could write a separate class that does all the dirty work and define it as a service in symfony, then it'll be reusable and really easy and clean to use in your code. You might even be able to find such a class somewhere in and just install it via composer, but I'm not really sure if a lib that does exactly what you need exists but it's worth to try to google it. Anyway, writing your own shouldn't be hard :)